# "No free license" error in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

The following error message occurs with some reports of our Crystal Reports application, when you try to open them a second time.

```
"A Crystal Reports job failed because a free license could not be obtained
in the time allocated"
```

It seems to be a problem only with some reports (with a lot of data in particular). Other reports work without any problem. But once the error message appeared, all reports will fail.

Can anyone tell me how the licensing mechanism of Crystal Reports works?
Where is the "free license" obtained from?
Can this be a time issue due to the amount of data?

-- edit --
From what we learned in the meantime, it seems to be a problem only with reports that called a particular long running PL/SQL package in the report command. And Crystal somehow doesn't like calling that twice.
And i guess the error message is just a secondary symptom and not the cause.

Comment: What kind of infrastructure do you have? Crystal Enterprise? or just some stand-alone developer copies of CR?